# Oculus Users.GetLoggedInUser() return empty string for DisplayName field

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, local, oculus

I am trying to get the userId, ImageURL, OculusID, and DisplayName for the local Oculus user in my Unity 3D game. I get correctly the userId, the ImageURL, and the OculusID, but the DisplayName is always an empty string.

Here is my code:

```
Users.GetLoggedInUser().OnComplete(message =>
{
    if (!message.IsError)
    {
        Oculus.Platform.Models.User user = message.GetUser();
        userId = user.ID;
        ImageURL = user.ImageURL;
        OculusID = user.OculusID;
        //Empty String
        Name = user.DisplayName;
    }
    else
    {
        var e = message.GetError();
        OvrAvatarLog.LogError($"Error loading user: {e.Message}.", "");
    }
});
```

How to get the DisplayName of the local Oculus User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to make another request to get the Display Name after you have the user id:

```
Users.Get(userId).OnComplete(message =>
{
    if (!message.IsError)
    {
        Oculus.Platform.Models.User user = message.GetUser();
        Name = user.DisplayName;
    }
    else
    {
        var e = message.GetError();
        OvrAvatarLog.LogError($"Error loading display name: {e.Message}.", "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the extra step is required in build, allthough not in the editor. Also, message.Data and message.GetUser() returns the same.

```
Users.GetLoggedInUser().OnComplete(message1 =>
{
    Log.Networking.Info($"message1.Data.DisplayName: {message1.Data.DisplayName}");
    Log.Networking.Info($"message1.GetUser().DisplayName: {message1.GetUser().DisplayName}");
    Users.Get(message1.Data.ID).OnComplete(message2 =>
    {
        Log.Networking.Info($"message2.Data.DisplayName: {message2.Data.DisplayName}");
        Log.Networking.Info($"message2.GetUser().DisplayName: {message2.GetUser().DisplayName}");
        user = message2.GetUser();
    });
});
```

```
// In editor with test user:
message1.Data.DisplayName: Will
message1.GetUser().DisplayName: Will
message2.Data.DisplayName: Will
message2.GetUser().DisplayName: Will
```

```
// In build with actual user:
message1.Data.DisplayName: 
message1.GetUser().DisplayName: 
message2.Data.DisplayName: Kvam
message2.GetUser().DisplayName: Kvam
```